# Load balancing servers

Tags: redirect, load-balancing, com+

I have a windows COM+ server connected to several SQL databases. The user sessions are stored in memory on the server. A MFC windows client connects to the server. The traffic is starting to get too high for just one server to handle so I would like to have one more. I plan to just redirect all new users to the new server like so:

my-server -- old users -- > my-server1

my-server -- new users -- > my-server2

but then I thought there might be some load balancing framework out there that might work better. What is the best way to solve the problem? What are the pros and cons with using a premade load balancer vs redirecting users.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the use of HAproxy for this. It supports both HTTP and plain TCP:

http://haproxy.1wt.eu/